# how to share sessions in weblogic

Tags: java, session, weblogic, locale

I have multiple applications running on weblogic. I need to let users to select language (English, Spanish, French, ...) and when they select, all applications they want to use must be base on the language they selected. When I save the `Locale` in session everything is ok for that application, but when user clicks on the other application (which is out of application scope) the language will be changed to default. Is there any way to share this value between all applications?

Comment: Related - https://community.oracle.com/thread/1012819?tstart=0

Comment: Do the option to set a Locale to a specific or all application is provided by all the applications or is it in some kind of master application?

Comment: @BheshGurung There is no master application. Basically when you come to the website and change the language (no matter what module you logged in) then you should be able to see all other modules (applications) in the same language you chosen. So for example if I have applications A,B,C running on my weblogic and I login to A and select French, then switch to B, I should be able to see B in French.

Comment: @BheshGurung the issue (I am not sure, just guessing) `session sharing` might have is if some values in the session conflict between different applications. so for example if I have `XYZ` set to `1` in application A and `XYZ` to `2` in application B. 
then I switch between applications what will happen to `XYZ`? Do I see them as I set on each module or will be changed?

Comment: If you are worried about the conflicts and also if the data that should be shared limited then I don't session sharing will the correct approach. I also think that a shared database could be actually a performance impact, could be wrong though. So finally, like @Elliot Frisch said, I think a cookie would be the best and optimal solution. Also, if you want SSO then also that's what you would be using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. One option is to save the user locale preference in a shared database. Another is to manually send a browser cookie.

Comment: If I save the Locale in a shared DB, any request must query on that table, which have a bad impact on the performance. For the cookies, I am not sure if it is shared between all applications. Can you please explain a bit more about that?

Comment: @pmp If the domain does not change, the cookie value will be sent from the browser to the server on every request. Making a database call is one solution, I would not *assume* that it will result in *bad impact on the performance*. That is [the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 1):

You have to share the HTTP sessions between the web applications (.war) in the same enterprise application (.ear). In the .ear's  weblogic-application.xml add the following setting:

```
<session-descriptor>
  <sharing-enabled>true</sharing-enabled>
</session-descriptor>
```

see: http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.2/weblogic-application.xsd and http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-javaee/1.2/weblogic-javaee.xsd

CAUTION:
  When you mix several .wars be careful about the cookie names. In our case mixing .wars (static resources) with default cookie name JSESSIONID and applications with explicitly defined session cookie names, the "shared" cookie name turned to be JSESSIONID, not the explicitly defined one.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your applications on same server try to configure JMS at server level on weblogic.
please look at this topic which will help you
http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=1987

Or

use session sharing state mode
https://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/18/sharing-session-state-between-jee-web-application-through-weblogic-session-descriptor-of-sharing-enabled/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).